# Change direction of existing particles

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, particles, skemitternode

I'm using SpriteKit's Particle Emitter system to construct a moving star field in the background with the player's ship in the center of the screen.

When the player touches an area of the screen I calculate the angle and animate the player sprite turning that direction.

When I apply it to the star field, however, the entire rectangle the star field is painted on rotates. What I want, however, are for the individual particles to simply start moving in a new direction.

It's the difference between rotating an entire sheet of paper with dots all over it and merely having the dots move toward a new angle. Does that make sense?

Here's what I have so far with the player rotating correctly but the star field "rotating like a whole sheet of paper":

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Choose one of the touches to work with
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    CGPoint offset = rwSub(location, center);

    SKEmitterNode *starfield = (SKEmitterNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"starfield"];

    SKSpriteNode *player = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"player"];

    SKAction *rotateNode = [SKAction rotateToAngle: (CGFloat)atan2(offset.y, offset.x) duration:0.5  shortestUnitArc:TRUE];
    [player runAction: rotateNode];

    SKAction *rotateStarfieldNode = [SKAction rotateToAngle: (CGFloat)(atan2(offset.y, offset.x) - M_PI_2) duration:0.5  shortestUnitArc:TRUE];
    [starfield runAction: rotateStarfieldNode];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change `SKEmitterNode`'s `particleRotation` property (https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEmitterNode/particleRotation)

Comment: Editing the particleRotation property doesn't seem to have a noticeable effect on the particles, existing or new.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the emissionAngle as follows:

```
[starField setEmissionAngle:(atan2(offset.y, offset.x) - M_PI_2)];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should probably do is have a `particleField` node or something and use that as the `targetNode` for the emitter that you have. (Also, put the emitter on this as a child node also). The `particleField` will just be a standard `SKNode` not an emitter. It will have an emitter as a child and all of the particles will be children also.

Treat it like a "particle layer" if you like.

Now you have a single node that "owns" all of the particles and the emitter etc...

The position of the particles and the direction of the particles all depends on the position of this `particleField` node.

Now you can rotate the `particleField` and move it around etc... (or scale it, etc...) and all of the particles will move along with it.